# Inverting voltage to PF motor

Tags: power-functions

I often use separate PF motor for each driven wheel. Sometimes the most interesting design of mechanism requires opposite polarity of power supply to motors. Is there any simple non-destructive way to invert voltage to one of motors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked into the [Power Functions Control Switch](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=8869-1) at all:

[image: Power Functions Control Switch]

This allows you to switch the direction of a motor.